# Rails public asset files error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, heroku, asset-pipeline

I have created a Rails app and deployed to heroku and I changed background image paths as suggested to make them work.

In my app, a user can upload his/her car pictures and I make them slider in the `car#show` action.

So when I push my app to heroku and upload some pictures to heroku, which rails save them to `public/uploads/picture/image`, it works fine. I can see images slider etc..

**But** on my local code as I did not upload pictures, there is no picture in `public/uploads/picture/image`. When I change lets say some js code css code locally then;

```
1.bundle exec rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production
2.git add -A
3.git commit -m "message"
4.git push heroku master
```

**Bang!** I cannot load the images that been uploaded before the push.It gives not found error (404)
So what should I do?.

Comment: i think you commit public folder , so every time you commit new changes it refresh you public folder too on server and everything in public folder is deleted .

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the problem, just do not know what I should do

Comment: you just add public folder to `gitignore`, it solve your problem.

Comment: could you tell me how do I do that?

Comment: find `.gitignore` file in your application root and add `/public` in that file . hope that solve your problem.

Comment: seems like I do not have .gitignore file?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar issue on Digital Ocean.

So what I did,
before pushing my new code. I used FireFTP and saved the **required folder in Public** to my Local machine.

And after pushing new code, again access server with FireFTP and added/overwrite my required folder, UPLOADER folder in your case.

Hopefully there might be a better soln. but it worked for me

Comment: Maybe I should change the path where it uploads pictures. ( I use carrierwave). If I use FireFTP everytime puff.. too much work. What if I use Amazon S3, does it solve the problem?

Comment: not sure about S3, hopefully it will work.
But S3 is an option, It depends on size of your app that Heroku is enogh or you have to Pay for S3.
Does yout DB remains same.?
I even have to replace my DB too